# How to replace a string with a foreach loop

Tags: php

I want to replace a string with a loop in php
 This is the string:-

```
$name=array("tom","vicky","raj");
str="{$loop_start} Good morning {$value} {$loop_end}";
i want it as:
foreach($name as $value){
echo Good morning $value;
}
```

Want to replace `{$loop_start}` with `foreach($name as $value){`

and `{$loop_end}` with `}`
   I am trying but not getting the solution of it
   Please help me if somebody know.

Thanks

Comment: you want to echo "Good morning" for each name in $name or you want entire foreach loop in string?

Comment: yes the entire foreach loop in a string

Answer (score 2):

PHP `explode()` will convert String into an array.

```
$name ='"tom","vicky","raj"';

$ino_array = explode(',', $name);

foreach($ino_array as $value) {
    echo 'Good morning '.$value.' <br />';
};
```

Comment: No semi colon required here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code $name='"tom","vicky","raj"' is a string.

```
<?php 

$str='"tom","vicky","raj"';
$str = substr($str,1);
$str = substr($str,0,-1);
$name = explode('","',$str);

foreach($name as $value){
echo "Good morning $value<br/>";
}
?>
```

This will might help you.